# Trying to make a "folded list" in python?

Tags: python, list

I need to make a "folded in half list" where I multiply the first and last term, second and second to last term, third and third to last term, etc.

I know how to make a list and how to print specific values from the list, but don't understand how to do math like this within the list, without simply typing each number and multiplying them.

So far all I have is a list (called a) with six terms, and though I know how to multiply the whole times an integer, I don't know how to make this "folded" thing. Will I need to end up making a loop of some sort? If so, how?

Edit: I should have specified that I need to make it via a function. Someone helped me make one via a method that worked great, but when I realized it needed to be a function I tried it again and it won't work. See the code below.

```
a = [10, 14, 21, 25 ,52, 55]
print('starting list:', a)
```

Finding the middle of the list
len(a)//2

Using (what I think is) a function to make a new list of first + last term, etc.
Term i is the term counted from the start of the list, term -(i+1) is the term counted from the bottom of the list

```
print(sum((a[i]) + (a[-(i + 1) ])) for i in range( len(a) // 2)
```

A code that works but isn't a function since it has brackets
foldedlist=[ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)]
print('folded list:', foldedlist)

Comment: Have you started reading about for loop?

Comment: Yes, the teacher gave us a very brief example about for loops, though our example didn't do any calculations, since it was a list made up of words and not numbers, so I couldn't really apply the example to this problem.

Comment: Do you know about using `for` loops with the `range()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, indexes in list can be positive or negative. Index -1 refers to last item, index -2 refers to second last item, etc. Hence, we must have:

L[0]*L[-1]+
L[1]*L[-2]+
L[2]*L[-3]+
...+
L[mid]*L[-(mid+1)]

The general formula is: **`L[i]*L[-(i+1)]`**. So, we can use the following code:

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
newList=[ list[i] * list[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(list) // 2)]
print(newList)
```

`len(list) // 2` is the index of middle of list.
**Output**: [6, 10, 12]

Answer (score 1):

Take your list, here:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Find the mid-way point (where the fold happens - you'll need to think about how this works for an odd-numbered length list)

```
l_mid = len(l) / 2
```

Make two sublists up to, and then from the mid-point

```
l1 = l[:l_mid]
l2 = l[l_mid:]
```

Create a container for the output and then iterate over both lists, with the latter reversed and append the product to the container.

```
output = []
for v1, v2 in zip(l1, reversed(l2)):
    output.append(v1 * v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
myList = [Yourlist]
newList = []
a = myList[:len(myList)//2]
b = myList[len(myList)//2:]
b.reverse()
for x,y in zip(a,b):
  newList.append(x*y)
```